# Scatter Plot into K-Means

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means, scatter-plot

I have this code the does the following:  Opens up a Csv file which looks like this but just many more rows

[image]

This is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df= pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/z647818/Desktop/tree/tree.csv", delimiter=";", encoding='unicode_escape')
df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'].str.split(',').str[0]
df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'].astype('int64', copy=False)

def scatterGraph(str1):

    dfstr = df[df['Description'] == str1]
    dfstrval = df[df['Description'] == str1]['Numbers']
    print(dfstrval)
    dfstr.plot(kind='scatter', x='Numbers', y='Numbers')

str1 = 'Journey has started' # In order to search for any other string just put that string here.
scatterGraph(str1)
```

What does the code do?
It goes to column Description, filters by the string name `Journey has started` and plots all the values of the column Numbers
The result looks like this.

[image]

I am looking for some help into turning the same structure of filtering by a certain string from a column and then plotting values into K-Means

Comment: sorry for worng answer, i just saw you plotted wrongly. any way i am coming to your point to do clustering i think you need at least two continuous variables.